# How to write a regex which matches all char-sequences without 'aaa'

Tags: regex

I tried to write that with negative lookahead, but the following regex doesn't work:

```
^.+(?!aaa).+$
```

it mathces all sequences at all. How to modify that?

Comment: Why would you need negative lookahead if an actual regular expression (in the Kleene sense of the word) suffices? I mean, doesn't `^([^a](aa?)?)*$` describe the language you want to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a `.*` to the look ahead group

```
^(?!.*aaa).+$
```

- `(?!.*aaa)` Negative look ahead ensures that there is no `aaa` in the string

[**Regex  Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xO3rH2/1)

**Issue with `^.+(?!aaa).+$`**

- `.` will match the first character in the string.
- `(?!aaa)` checks if the first character is not followed by `aaa`. Clearly this is not something we expect. Rather we need to search the entire string for the sequance and not to limit the search after the first character.

Where as

- `(?!.*aaa)` scales the search to the entire string.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?:(?!aaa).)*$
```

You can also try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/xO3rH2/2

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                       (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      aaa                      'aaa'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                       string
```